# IIR Lattice Filter in C programming

Tags: signal-analysis, adaptive-filters, c

I would like to implement Lattice IIR filter in c, i can't defined the value of gN, i know that x(n) = fN(n), but how to initialize gN ?. you can find the algorithm here : n[image: lattice iir filter]

Answer (score 4):

assume all of this (except `k[0]` and the output `y[]`) gets defined.  states `g[]` are initialized to zero.

```
int N, NUM_SAMPLES;
float g[N+1], v[N+1], k[N+1];
float x[NUM_SAMPLES], y[NUM_SAMPLES];
```

then the sample processing would look like this:

```
int n = 0;
while (n < NUM_SAMPLES)
    {
    float f = x[n];
    
    float acc = 0.0;
    int m = N;
    while (m > 0)
        {
        f -= k[m]*g[m-1];
        g[m] = k[m]*f + g[m-1];
        acc += v[m]*g[m];
        m--;
        }
    g[0] = f;
    acc += v[0]*g[0];
    
    y[n] = acc;
    n++;
    }
```

that is, i think, the essential C code.

Comment: O&S has a general recursion technique to map the Lattice coefficients to and from the Direct Form coefficients.  For just second order, [I have listed this answer to convert Direct Form coefficients to Lattice](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/48255/real-time-modulated-iir-filter/48299#48299).  Using the [Cookbook](https://webaudio.github.io/Audio-EQ-Cookbook/audio-eq-cookbook.html) will give you an idea what the Direct Form coefficient values are.

Answer (score 2):

you have a programming issue here.  i have C code for a lattice i did long ago.  dunno if i wanna dig it out (i used to sell it for money, but that was long ago).  just think this:  at the beginning of your sampling instance when $x[n]$ is defined, consider what else is defined and it is the outputs of all of the unit delay blocks (marked $z^{-1}$).  those numbers (and the $k_m$ coefficients) are what you know at the beginning.

what must you calculate after that?

first thing is $f_{N-1}[n]$ and $g_N[n]$.

then you can calculate $f_{N-2}[n]$ and $g_{N-1}[n]$.

then you calculate $f_{N-3}[n]$ and $g_{N-2}[n]$.

then you calculate $f_{N-4}[n]$ and $g_{N-3}[n]$.

...

last intermediate state you will calculate is $f_0[n]$ and $g_1[n]$ and finally $g_0[n]=f_0[n]$.

then you can calculate $y[n]$ as a dot-product of all of the $v_m$ coefficients and the intermediate states $g_m[n]$.

then lastly you update your states of the $z^{-1}$ unit delay blocks for the following sample. (this updating can be done *naturally* with no wasted instruction cycles.  when you calculate $g_{N}[n]$ and $f_{N-1}[n]$, you need knowledge of $g_{N-1}[n-1]$ which is the state.  but after that calculation, then you will never need $g_{N-1}[n-1]$ again and you can replace it with the calculated value of $g_{N-1}[n]$ in anticipation of the following sample period.)

the state of the block on the right will be $g_0[n]$, the block to the left of that is $g_1[n]$ and finally the the output of the state of the block on the left is $g_{N-1}[n]$.

now you are done with this sample and ready to compute the next sample when its input, $x[n+1]$ comes in.

Comment: thank you for your help
Please can you explain more how to calculate  is fN−1[n] and gN[n] ?
you said that i have to calculate gN[n], but to be able to calculate gN[n], we have define firstly gN-1[n], no ?!!

Comment: look at your signal flow diagram.  and remember the **outputs** of all of the states (those are the blocks with $z^{-1}$ on them) are **known** at the beginning of your sample period.  so while you do not yet know the **input** to that block (which is $g_{N-1}[n]$) you know the output of it because it was the input do that block the previous sample, i.e. you **do** know $g_{N-1}[n-1]$.  and the initial value of it is zero (i.e. $g_{N-1}[-1]=0$).

Comment: ok, it means gN-1[n] = input[n] in the beginning !!

Answer (score 0):

this is my code, it works just for one stage, i mean just for fN−1[n] and gN[n], one coefficient. but when i try to calculate the rest it doesn't works

```
for (i=0;i<block_size;i++)
    {
    f_in[i]=input[i];
    g_in[i]=input[i];
    }

for (j=nb_coefficient;j>0;j--)
    {

        for (i=block_size-1;i>=0;i--)
            {

            g_in[i]=g_in[i-1];

            printf("%f %f %f \n",input[i],f_in[i],g_in[i]);

            output[i] = f_in[i] - parkor_coefficient[j]*g_in[i];
            printf("%f\n",output[i]);

            g_out[i] = output[i]*parkor_coefficient[j] + g_in[i];
            printf("%f\n",g_out[i]);

            }
            for(i=0;i<block_size;i++)
                {
                f_in[i]=output[i];

                    if(j==1)
                    {
                        g_out[i]=output[i]; 
                    } 
                }


    }
```

}

Comment: i love your C indentation style.  it's exactly the same as mine.

Comment: listen. i ain't gonna write your code for you. but i can make sure you're heading in the right direction.  lemme know.

Comment: i guess three and a half years later, i wrote the code for the OP.