# Biquad Type-II Coefficient Generation

Tags: biquad

I have a Biquad II filter implementation in my embedded environment and I'm trying to find some equations to generate the coefficients for it.

I have already found the [Audio Eq Cookbook](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/), which simply describes how to calculate all of the coefficients for Type I.

LPF: (Taken from Audio Eq Cookbook, **Type I Equations**)

```
omega = 2*PI*frequency/sampleRate

sin   = sin(omega)
cos   = cos(omega)

alpha = sin/(2*Q)                                     (if Q is specified)
      = sin*sinh[ ln(2)/2 * bandwidth * omega/sin ]   (if bandwidth is specified)

            b0 =  (1 - cos)/2
            b1 =   1 - cos
            b2 =  (1 - cos)/2
            a0 =   1 + alpha
            a1 =  -2*cos
            a2 =   1 - alpha
```

What are the equations for type II coefficients?

Comment: Why would the coefficients depend on biquad type ?

Comment: Can I use biquad I coefficients for II type as well?

Comment: hay, i didn't see this until now, 2 weeks later.  the coefficients for the Direct Form 1 and Direct Form 2 are the same.  but these coefficients have to be massaged a bit if your implementation is a form like Lattice or Ladder or some other State Variable Forms.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson hey robert, please elaborate since I'm desperately wanting to implement a ladder filter. Can you lead me to a reading source? or even better, a math like this simple?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson lol, robert it is you! you are the author of audio eq cookbook, huge fan! such an honour! :) thank you for this lovely source, It saved me like a years work maybe. Thank you! Your page in musicdsp is down by the way, is there any other sites hosting your original writing?

While I find you here, would like to ask another question. When my filter drops down below 200-300 hz, some distortion/noise begin to rumble in low end, especially with high Q. Is there a way to eliminate this? Using direct form II transposed.

Comment: for the lattice, i got this [answer for how to calculate the coefficients from the Direct Form](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/48255/real-time-modulated-iir-filter/48299#48299) and this [answer for how to code it](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/42006/iir-lattice-filter-in-c-programming/42008#42008).

Comment: that musicdsp is often down.  looks like you can find the [cookbook text here](http://www.musicdsp.org/en/latest/_downloads/3e1dc886e7849251d6747b194d482272/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt).

Comment: thank you, i will try to implement that. any idea about that low end rumble?